# How do I select records where created_at = a specific hour?

Tags: laravel-5

In my Laravel 5.6 app I am able to use Carbon to figure out the current time and grab the hour like this;

```
$time = Carbon::now();
$hour = $time->format("H");
```

What I want to do now is find records who's created_at are from today;

```
$user= User::where('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();
```

And more specifically have the same hour as $hour.  I see functions for whereMonth(), whereWeek() and whereDay() but nothing time specific.

What's the best way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: You could use Laravel's `->whereRaw()` with a combination of your DB's `DATE_FORMAT` equiv. for `hour`. Alternatively, you can get all the records for today (likely using `->whereDate()`), and use Collection's `->filter()` logic to compare hours using `Carbon`. Lots for approaches.

Comment: Right, I guess I need to be more specific.  If I use the collection filter method, how do I explicitly compare created_at hour?

Comment: Pretty simple; just format and compare via Carbon: `return Carbon::parse($record->created_at)->format("H") == $time->format("H");` Might not even need to `::parse()`; most times `created_at` is already a `Carbon` variable.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking, this is how I did it.

```
    $users = User::whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())->get();
    $filtered = $users->filter(function($user) {
        $time = Carbon::now();
        return $user->created_at->format("H") == $time->format("H");
    });
```

Thanks for the nudge in the right direction @Tim Lewis.